# Has anybody tried to Debug using JTAG/BDM?

Tags: software-development, driver

Is there a useable JTAG/BDM interface available on the Raspberry Pi?

What hardware Debugger is needed for Debugging ?

Can [Open OCD](http://openocd.sourceforge.net/) be used?

Answer (score 8):

The Revision 2.0 of the model B Raspberry Pi has exposed the JTAG pins.

See http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1929

Comment: So with the Pins available, which Software / Hardware is needed to use the Pins for Debugging?

Answer (score 7):

You can find a lot of informations [here](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/master/armjtag). Unfortunately, using JTAG on RPi is not straight forward. To be honest, just because it's so problematic, I didn't bother to get it working. Here's what I know, however:

Not all JTAG signals are easily available. All but all are on GPIO connector (not on P2 JTAG connector - it's a VideoCore JTAG, not ARM and AFAIK it's not usable for people outside of Broadcom). The additional pin is on S5 (CSI header) connector, you will probably have to solder it out. Here are pins that are needed (more on this on dwelch67 site, you can also find information about GPIO alternate pins functions on [raspberrypi wiki](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals)):

```
  ARM_VREF    P1-1
  ARM_TRST    P1-15
  ARM_TDO     P1-18
  ARM_TCK     P1-22
  ARM_TDI     P1-7
  ARM_TMS     S5-11
  ARM_GND     P1-25
```

**EDIT: As [@Damian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/1422/damian-dixon) pointed out, on revision 2.0 of PCB, missing ARM_TMS signal was connected to pin 13 on P1 so soldering should not be necessary any more.**

Now, it's not the only problem. By default all those pins are configured to be GPIO pins, not JTAG ones. They have to be reconfigured in software and AFAIK there is no support for this in Foundation bootloader. Dwelch67 wrote his own bootloader (next stage bootloader) that does just that. You can download it from the link provided at the top of this answer.

As for the hardware, any ARM11 JTAG hardware *should* be OK. As mentioned earlier, I havn't personally tested any so I can't do any recommendations. And yes, OpenOCD can be used.
There is even small project (also done by dwelch67) to build very simple and cheap JTAG hardware based on cheap board like [Launchpad](http://www.ti.com/LaunchPad). See his [github repo](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/master/jtagproxy)

Comment: Hi "Christofer" Thanks for posting some information. It would be great if you could expand you answer. Possibly what cables are needed- how to connect them, a picture or two goes a thousand words. Otherwise I think it is worth being a comment; Users can go and explore it on their own time. Welcome to Raspberry Pi SE :-) Witamy!

Comment: I've added some more informations. That's actually all I can tell on this subject and I thought that some small amount of information is better than nothing. And since it's the only answer, I believe there's not much other information about it out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this converter SN74LVC8T245 from TI
http://www.ti.com/product/sn74lvc8t245

Comment: Welcome to Pi.SE... Please expand on your recommendation.