# RaspberryPi with TRACE32

Tags: boot

First, I read this [Has anybody tried to Debug using JTAG/BDM?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/has-anybody-tried-to-debug-using-jtag-bdm)

Has any one tried to debug the RaspberryPi using TRACE32?
I hacked around the GPIO's needed for JTAG.
I used armjtag https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/master/armjtag.

I couldn't manage to make a valid connection. TRACE32 says "Emulation debug port fail". I used the below cmm. Any ideas?

```
SYStem.RESet
SYStem.CPU  ARM1176JZF
SYStem.Option ResBreak OFF
SYStem.Option WaitReset ON
SYStem.Up
SYStem.JtagClock 1MHz
```